# Adding space between text in xml xslt rule

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xsl rule that kinda works:

```
        <xsl:element name="Section">            
            <xsl:for-each select="section/*[preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('SEC')[contains(., 'end=&quot;lead&quot;')] or preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('section')[contains(., 'end=&quot;lead&quot;')]]
                    [following-sibling::processing-instruction('SEC')[contains(., 'end=&quot;tail&quot;')] or following-sibling::processing-instruction('section')[contains(., 'end=&quot;tail&quot;')]] ">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>   
            </xsl:for-each>     
        </xsl:element>
```

The correct section is found in the source, and contains text like:

```
<row>
<entry/>
<entry/>
<entry>glaucoma</entry>
<entry>glaucoma</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry/>
<entry/>
<entry/>
<entry>Band keratopathy</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry/>
<entry>Surgeries</entry>
<entry>Lensectomy</entry>
<entry>Lensectomy</entry>
</row>
```

Which results in this:
    keratopathySurgeriesLensectomyLensectomyTrabeculectomyTrabeculectomytrabeculotomyTrabeculotomyAhmed

Is there a way to add spaces the the result text?

I've tried things like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', ., ' ')" />
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="." separator="&#x20;"/>
```

but the text I want is still continuous. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you provide the full XSLT? To make sure we are not missing anything that would cause this kind of behavior.

Comment: The XSLT sample does not seem to correspond to your XML input. The XSLT is looking for children of a `section` element, which is not in your XML, and also contains code to check for processing instructions, which are also not in your XML.

Comment: While your question is tagged as [tag:xslt-1.0] you use the `seperator` attribute which only exists in XSLT 2 and later.

Comment: @cdan, thank you for that comment, I looked to and saw that I had: <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> which affected the result. I removed it and was able to get a result I could work with. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :-)